# Why are my array elements getting overridden?

Tags: c

I stared at this code for at least 4 hours.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm updating the array `hand[5][2]` with a simple for loop.

The values stored in `hand[0][2]`, `hand[0][3]` and `hand[0][4]` keep getting overwritten.

I used the debugger to go slowly through every single line but I still don't
understand why I'm getting different values.

This is the output I'm getting

```
hand[0][0] = 0
hand[0][1] = 1
hand[0][2] = 2
hand[0][3] = 3
hand[0][4] = 4
hand[1][0] = 0
hand[1][1] = 1
hand[1][2] = 2
hand[1][3] = 3
hand[1][4] = 4
0 1 0 1 2 // WHY ARE hand[0][2],hand[0][3],hand[0][4] not the same????
0 1 2 3 4
```

Code:

```
int main() {
    //tests();
    int hand[5][2];
    int a[5], b[5];
    char line[100];
    int player = 0;
    int card = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        hand[player][card] = card;
        printf("hand[%d][%d] = %d\n", player, card, hand[player][card]);
        card++;
        if (card == 5) { player++; card = 0; }
    }
    // print first hand
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("%d ", hand[0][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // print second hand
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("%d ", hand[1][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: instead of the `if (card == 5) { player++; card = 0; }` you can use the mod (%) operator to get the same effect (will be a bit slower in some cases though) : `hand[i / 5][i % 5] = card;` (this is not the answer since personjerry already answered below)

Comment: C++ style: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13111470/ or at least http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61588103c6184ee5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int hand[5][2];` should be `int hand[2][5];`

Comment: Agree, you have 2 hands with 5 cards in each, the way you have it states you have 5 hands with 2 cards in each